# Format price with no decimal to ".-"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I give you quick example of my need:

- I have prices like: 1 or 1.35
- I want to display 1.- and keep 1.35

I did not find any workaround to do it with javascript. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide us any code where the remainders are being removed? I don't really see any issues here.

Comment: seems like a lazy question.. have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You could replace .00 with .-

Comment: @Luc yes but my number is not formatted with .00. So i guess first it has to be formatted with .00 and then replaced by .- ?

Comment: You can use something like this: `num.toFixed(2).toString().replace('.00','.-')`, but it won't work for really big numbers that start with 'X00' because they become `1.-25531231255535e+21`. Probably should use a regex at that point.

Answer (score -1):

```
var n = -1.35;

n = Math.abs(n);

var formatted = n.toFixed(0);
console.log(formatted);
```